# Drawing a varying waveform with labels

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphs

I am trying to draw the following graph using tikzpicture. I dont know what would be the function graph for this as all time periods are varying. How can I draw this in latex?

[image]

Edit: I am able to draw the graph. Now I am trying to add the Execution label.
This is the code I have written:

```
    \documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
   \usepackage{pgfplots}
   \pgfplotsset{width=10cm,height=6cm,compat=1.18}
   \usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows}
   \begin{document}     
   \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.5cm,y=1.5cm]
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (9,0) node[below] {\textbf{Time}};
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,2.5) node[left] {\textbf{Energy}};
    
    % Draw axes with no labels or numbers
    %\draw[->] (0,0) -- (9,0);
    %\draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,1.5);
    
    % Draw intermittent energy system
    \draw[thick] (0,0.5) to[bend left] (1,2) -- (2,0.5) to[bend left] (3,2) -- (4,0.5) to[bend left] (4.5,2) -- (5.5,0.5) to[bend left] (6.5,2) -- (7.5,0.5) ;
    
    % Draw dashed lines for zero crossing
    \draw[dashed] (0,0) -- (9,0);
    
    % Label turn-off and turn-on thresholds
    \draw[dashed] (0,0.5) -- (8.6,0.5) node[pos=0.6, below] {\textbf{Turn-off threshold}};
    \draw[dashed] (0,2) -- (8.6,2) node[pos=0.6, above] {\textbf{Turn-on threshold}};
    % Draw y-axis ticks from 0 to 1
    %\foreach \y in {0,0.2,...,1}
    %\draw (0.1,\y) -- (0.1,\y);
    \end{tikzpicture}    
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Please add the missing parts to your code ... so everybody can copy and compile it. Thanks. // A screenshot of your codes result may help understanding your approach at a glance.

Comment: Please extend your code snippet to a complete [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that), as stated in this website rules. That would avoid helpers to reedo everything from scratch.

Comment: Maybe something like `\draw[thick] (0,0.5) to[bend left] (1,1) -- (2,0.5) ...` could be a (partial) solution?

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I have edited the code. How can I add the execution label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an approach that uses a `\pic` for drawing each piece of the curve, with the cyan rectangle, the left 'pin' and the time label (if there is one). It creates some coordinates too.

```
\tikzset
{%
   pics/wave/.style n args={4}{% #1 = x (maximun), #2 = y (maximum), #3 = x (end point) #4 = label
     code={%
       \pgfmathsetmacro\myangle{atan{#2/#1}}
       \pgfmathsetmacro\pinwd{0.04}
       \coordinate (-max) at (#1,#2);
       \coordinate (-end) at (#1+#3,0);
       \coordinate (-pin) at (#1-0.075,0.85*#2);
       % rectangle
       \fill[pic actions,draw=none] (-max) rectangle (-end);
       % pin
       \fill[pic actions,draw=none,even odd rule]
            (-pin) ++ (-0.075,-0.075)             rectangle ++ (0.15,0.15)
            (-pin) ++ (-0.075+\pinwd,-0.075+\pinwd) rectangle ++ (0.15-2*\pinwd,0.15-2*\pinwd);
       % label
       \ifblank{#4}{}
       {
         \draw[gray!75!black,|-|,loosely dashed,shorten <=0.025cm,shorten >=0.025cm] (0,0.15*#2) --++ (#1,0) node[midway,above] {#4};
       }
       % curve
       \draw[pic actions,fill=none] (0,0) to[out=0.5*\myangle+45,in=180+0.5*\myangle] (-max) -- (-end);
     }},
   curve/.style={thick,fill=cyan!70}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\small,line cap=round,line join=round]
%\draw[gray!30] (0,0) grid[step=0.5] (8,3);
% axes
\draw[latex-latex,very thick] (8,0) -- (0,0) node[midway,below] {\bfseries Time} --
                           (0,3) node[midway,sloped,yshift=3mm] {\bfseries Stored Energy};
% curve
\pic[curve] (1) at (0,0.4) {wave={1.5}{1.9}{0.3}{}};
\pic[curve] (2) at (1-end) {wave={2}{1.9}{0.3}{$t_1$}};
\pic[curve] (3) at (2-end) {wave={1}{1.9}{0.3}{$t_2$}};
\pic[curve] (4) at (3-end) {wave={1.7}{1.9}{0.3}{$t_3$}};
% dashed lines
\draw[thick,dashed,orange!70!black] (0,0.4) --++ (8,0);
\draw[thick,dashed,teal!70]         (0,2.3) --++ (8,0);
% labels
\node[cyan]       (Ex) at (2.7,2.5) {Execution};
\node[teal]            at (5.2,2.5) {Turn \textbf{on} Threshold};
\node[orange!70!black] at (5.2,0.2) {Turn \textbf{off} Threshold};
\draw[cyan] (Ex.west) --++ (-1,0) |- (1-pin);
\draw[cyan] (Ex.340)  |-  (4-pin);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]